# foreach step 5 steps forward in an array

Tags: php

How can I step forward 5 steps when using foreach to output an arrays value? So In this the put will be 1, 5

```
$array = ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    echo $value; //Where do I tell it to move 5 paces forward?
    echo "<br/ >";
}
```

If a foreach loop cannot be used, I'm willing to use something else. I don't think "while" or "for" can be used here?

Comment: 2 ways. Add a counter and use it as index. Add +5 after each iteration. Or use modulous operator.

Comment: Should it *always* move forward 5 places?

Comment: If you move forward 5 steps wouldn't the output be 1,6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i+=5) {
    echo $array[$i];
    echo "<br/ >";
}
```

Comment: This did the job (with a few amendments to the arrays starting value and beginning i at 1). Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a while loop. Just set an index outside of the loop, and add 5 to it on each iteration of the loop. When the index is larger than the length of the list, terminate the loop.

A more compact way to express these instructions is a for loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i = $i+5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not numerically indexed

```
$count = -1;
foreach ($array as &$value) {
  $count++;
  if ($count%4 != 0) continue;
  echo "$value".PHP_EOL;
}
```